# How do I protect my App API from external exploitation?

Tags: node.js, angular, api

I don't know if this is the right platform to ask this kind of question,
but I have an app that is separated between frontend **(Angular)** and backend/API (**Nodejs**). Now the API exposes public endpoints to be used by the frontend. Now how do I protect the API from being used or exploited by other parties and only keep it to my **Angular** app? I thought of using an HTTP only cookie but it seems its visible when someone opens the developer's tools on the request's headers.

I am completely out of ideas, thanks in advance.

Comment: HTTPS and certificate pinning could be a good start

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to make your site 100% secure but you can slow attackers down, or convince them on to a less secure site if you cover the owasp top 10 and have some transport protection.

Transport protection

- HTTPS: either use a solution with https already configured, like heroku or now.sh or use [letsencrypt.org](https://letsencrypt.org)
- Authentication - There are loads of solutions and you would need to figure out how important the data is you are trying to secure.  JWT is a good starting point as it is the easiest and relatively secure.

OWASP attacks.

The OWASP top 10 is here:
https://www.owasp.org/images/7/72/OWASP_Top_10-2017_%28en%29.pdf.pdf

You can cover the majority of the list by using a library such as JOI, https://www.npmjs.com/package/joi and setting up the schemas so you only allow input that is absolutely necessary.  Use whitelists of valid parameters rather than allow any string.

The only other precaution I would take is to use the npm library helmet, https://www.npmjs.com/package/helmet.  This covers most of the XSS points

Those are probably the main points you need to cover, that will deter most opportunistic crackers

Answer (score 2):

You can secure your API with a token using OAuth2, I don't know in angular to much but the best practice is to secure the nodejs with JWT Token.

### Helpful link [Creating an API authenticated with OAuth 2 in Node.js](https://resources.infosecinstitute.com/securing-web-apis-part-ii-creating-an-api-authenticated-with-oauth-2-in-node-js/#gref)

[Beer Locker: Building a RESTful API With Node - OAuth2 Server](http://scottksmith.com/blog/2014/07/02/beer-locker-building-a-restful-api-with-node-oauth2-server/)

--